# Spotipy Oauth2 Flow Storing Tokens

Tags: python, spotipy

I am trying to implement oauth2 for a spotify app I am making with spotipy. I may have a bad understanding of how the flask session works, but I am trying to generate a Spotify API access token using SpotiPY with the Authorization Code Flow, and store it in Flask's session storage.

The program doesn't seem to be able to store it, and therefore later runs in to an error when trying to call it. Here is a visual explanation with images and captions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvhQG.jpg

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, make_response,session,redirect
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from credentz import *
import time
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = SSK

API_BASE = 'https://accounts.spotify.com'

# Make sure you add this to Redirect URIs in the setting of the application dashboard
REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080"

SCOPE = 'playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public,user-top-read'

# Set this to True for testing but you probaly want it set to False in production.
SHOW_DIALOG = True


# authorization-code-flow Step 1. Have your application request authorization; 
# the user logs in and authorizes access
@app.route("/")
def verify():
    # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
    sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    print(auth_url)
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

# authorization-code-flow Step 2.
# Have your application request refresh and access tokens;
# Spotify returns access and refresh tokens
@app.route("/api_callback")
def api_callback():
    # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
    sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)

    # Saving the access token along with all other token related info
    session["token_info"] = token_info


    return redirect("index")

# authorization-code-flow Step 3.
# Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API;
# Spotify returns requested data
@app.route("/go", methods=['POST'])
def go():
    session['token_info'], authorized = get_token(session)
    session.modified = True
    if not authorized:
        return redirect('/')
    data = request.form
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=session.get('token_info').get('access_token'))
    response = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=data['num_tracks'], time_range=data['time_range'])

    # print(json.dumps(response))

    return render_template("results.html", data=data)

# Checks to see if token is valid and gets a new token if not
def get_token(session):
    token_valid = False
    token_info = session.get("token_info", {})

    # Checking if the session already has a token stored
    if not (session.get('token_info', False)):
        token_valid = False
        return token_info, token_valid

    # Checking if token has expired
    now = int(time.time())
    is_token_expired = session.get('token_info').get('expires_at') - now < 60

    # Refreshing token if it has expired
    if (is_token_expired):
        # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
        sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
        token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(session.get('token_info').get('refresh_token'))

    token_valid = True
    return token_info, token_valid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I found this code elsewhere on the site. However, it appears that the module "credentz" doesn't exist. Anyone have an idea of how to store Tokens for multiple spotify accounts in spotipy?

Comment: I have written an [example](https://tekore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/auth_server.html) authenticating server that does exactly that, with my own Web API wrapper, [Tekore](https://pypi.org/project/tekore/). Maybe it could be of help to you. It is somewhat similar to Spotipy, so maybe you could adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

An example flask API app has been added in the spotipy repo https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py